# how to get all job url from jenkins script console

Tags: jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

when I run following code in Jenkins script console then I get the job location but I am wondering if there is a way to get whole url to the job rather then just the path.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).each  {it ->
    println it.fullName;
}
```

output is
Results:
aa/prj1/prj/pr
bb/prj1/prj/pr
cc/prj2/prj/pr

what I am trying to do is to get
https://jenkinsmy.aa.com/job/aa/job/prj1/job/prj2/master

that way I can directly reach the job or config files for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the script console but you can get all the job url from normal groovy script.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def jobUrl = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class)
                    jobUrl.each { iti ->
                        println "${JENKINS_URL}/job/${iti.fullName}"
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it was perfect, just little hurdle was that it was giving ci Pipeline script not permitted error but after disable use groovy sandbox by unchecking the Use Groovy Sandbox in the job config I was able to run this.

Comment: one problem is that they are going to wrong urls. The url's that are coming from here is giving urls like https://jennkins.ab.com/job/aa/bb/dd while jobs are actually located in heeps://jenkins.aa.com/job/aa/job/bb/job/dd. THis could be due to jenkins upgrade but wondering if there is any solution to this as well

Comment: Also I was wondering if there is a way to capture branch name as well. THe fullName only gives the project name but I would also like to get first branch name inside the project if possible. Could you please help @Dashrath Mundkar

Comment: You must use `iti.absoluteUrl` instead of `"${JENKINS_URL}/job/${iti.fullName}"`